# VBA code using variable without defining it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro that someone else wrote and am confused because they don't define a variable but are still using it.  1) is this possible and 2) how does excel/vba know what the variable is supposed to be?  The variable used is "theCell" and there is no definition anywhere.  Code below, and thanks:

```
Sub DoTheWork()

Sheets("All Data").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Set homebook = ActiveWorkbook
Set homeSheet = Sheets("All Data")
topRow = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For Each theCell In Selection
    If (theCell.Value <> theCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
        Range("A" & topRow & ":AS" & theCell.Row).Select
        Sheets("e-TAR").Select
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        Set copySheet = ActiveSheet
        Set copyBook = ActiveWorkbook
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, it is considered bad practice.  Unassigned variables are Variant, which means that excel makes it what is needed the first time it is used in this case it is a range variable.

Comment: Use of undefined variables is allowed if you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module containing the code.  It's good practise to always use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't know what it is supposed to be so it creates one on-the-fly as a variant type which can handle pretty much anything assigned to it including objects and arrays.

The 'best practise' is to put an **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each codesheet in the declarations area. This can be performed automatically upon the creation of each codesheet by setting the **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page.

This will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration.